# Check reaction pagination button

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I have a command that moves a sequence of images back and forth through 2 buttons:

```
left = '⏪'
right = '⏩'

def predicate(message, l, r):
    def check(reaction, user):
        if reaction.message.id != message.id or user == Bot.user:
            return False
        if l and reaction.emoji == left:
            return True
        if r and reaction.emoji == right:
            return True
        return False

    return check
```

some stuffs

```
mmsg = ("1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png")

index = 0
while True:
    msg = await Bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, mmsg[index])
    l = index != 0
    r = index != len(mmsg) - 1
    if l:
        await Bot.add_reaction(msg, left) 
    if r:
        await Bot.add_reaction(msg, right)
    Bot.wait_for_reaction
    reaction, ctx.message.author = await Bot.wait_for_reaction(check=predicate(msg, l, r))
    if reaction.emoji == left:
        index -= 1
    elif reaction.emoji == right:
        index += 1
    await Bot.delete_message(msg)
```

But when someone other than you clicks the button, the command works, that's not supposed to happen, only the one who executed the command should be able to click the buttons, as shown in the predicate check, what should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `predicate` check doesn't check for that.  It just checks that the reaction didn't come from the bot.  You can add a `user` argument to `wait_for_reaction` to only accept reactions from that `ctx.message.author`:

```
mmsg = ("1.png", "2.png", "3.png", "4.png")

index = 0
while True:
    msg = await Bot.send_file(ctx.message.channel, mmsg[index])
    l = index != 0
    r = index != len(mmsg) - 1
    if l:
        await Bot.add_reaction(msg, left) 
    if r:
        await Bot.add_reaction(msg, right)
    reaction, _ = await Bot.wait_for_reaction(check=predicate(msg, l, r), user=ctx.message.author)
    if reaction.emoji == left:
        index -= 1
    elif reaction.emoji == right:
        index += 1
    await Bot.delete_message(msg)
```

You were also assigning to `ctx.message.author`, which I removed. There's no reason to assign to a `Context`